# Why after selecting cell programmatically - cell is not interaction?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uikit

I set a cell in the collectionView selected programmatically :

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(with: FAFavouriteCategoryCell.self, for: indexPath)!
        let currentCategory = categories[indexPath.row]
        cell.isSelected = selectedCategories.contains(currentCategory.categoryID)
        cell.configCell(category: currentCategory)
        return cell
    }
```

after this all selected cells not working. I can't click on It.
If I clicked method `shouldDeselectItemAt` not calling

Comment: You should instead call `collectionView.selectItem(at indexPath: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)` instead of `cell.isSelected`.

Comment: @Larme I need to select it at the init table moment. Where I should call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `selectItem` like this

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(with: FAFavouriteCategoryCell.self, for: indexPath)!
        let currentCategory = categories[indexPath.row]
        if selectedCategories.contains(currentCategory.categoryID) {
            collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .left) //Add this line
            cell.isSelected = true
        } else {
            collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false)
            cell.isSelected = false
        }
        cell.configCell(category: currentCategory)
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Good. It is work but after the first tap ( I need to show selected items at the init moment

Comment: Shouldn't you call deselectItem in the else (non written) to avoid reuse potential issue? Is the isSelected necessary?